# Steps to creating an NFA from a regular expression

Tags: theory, compiler-theory, nfa

I'm having issues 'describing each step' when creating an NFA from a regular expression. The question is as follows:

Convert the following regular expression to a non-deterministic ﬁnite-state automaton (NFA), clearly describing the steps of the algorithm that you use:
(b|a)*b(a|b)

I've made a simple 3-state machine but it's very much from intuition.
This is a question from a past exam written by my lecturer, who also wrote the following explanation of Thompson's algorithm: http://www.cs.may.ie/staff/jpower/Courses/Previous/parsing/node5.html

Can anyone clear up how to 'describe each step clearly'? It just seems like a set of basic rules rather than an algorithm with steps to follow.

Maybe there's an algorithm I've glossed over somewhere but so far I've just created them with an educated guess.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Short version for general approach.**
There's an algo out there called the Thompson-McNaughton-Yamada Construction Algorithm or sometimes just "Thompson Construction." One builds intermediate NFAs, filling in the pieces along the way, while respecting operator precedence: first parentheses, then Kleene Star (e.g., a*), then concatenation (e.g., ab), followed by alternation (e.g., a|b).

**Here's an in-depth walkthrough for building (b|a)*b(a|b)'s NFA**

*Building the top level*

1. Handle parentheses. Note: In actual implementation, it can make sense to handling parentheses via a recursive call on their contents. For the sake of clarity, I'll defer evaluation of anything inside of parens.
2. Kleene Stars: only one * there, so we build a placeholder Kleene Star machine called P (which will later contain b|a).
   Intermediate result:
   [image: Non-Deterministic Finite Automata for P*]
3. Concatenation: Attach P to b, and attach b to a placeholder machine called Q (which will contain (a|b). Intermediate result:
   [image: Non-Deterministic Finite Automata for P*bQ]
4. There's no alternation outside of parentheses, so we skip it.

Now we're sitting on a P*bQ machine. (Note that our placeholders P and Q are just concatenation machines.) We replace the P edge with the NFA for b|a, and replace the Q edge with the NFA for a|b via recursive application of the above steps.

---

*Building P*

1. Skip. No parens.
2. Skip. No Kleene stars.
3. Skip. No contatenation.
4. Build the alternation machine for b|a. Intermediate result:
   [image: NFA for b or a]

---

*Integrating P*

Next, we go back to that P*bQ machine and we tear out the P edge. We have the *source of the P edge* serve as the starting state for the P machine, and the *destination of the P edge* serve as the destination state for the P machine. We also make that state reject (take away its property of being an accept state). The result looks like this:
[image]

---

*Building Q*

1. Skip. No parens.
2. Skip. No Kleene stars.
3. Skip. No contatenation.
4. Build the alternation machine for a|b. Incidentally, alternation is commutative, so a|b is logically equivalent to b|a. (Read: skipping this minor footnote diagram out of laziness.)

---

*Integrating Q*

We do what we did with P above, except replacing the Q edge with the intermedtae b|a machine we constructed. This is the result:
[image]

Tada! Er, I mean, QED.

---

**Want to know more?**

All the images above were generated using [an online tool for automatically converting regular expressions to non-deterministic finite automata](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa). You can find its [source code for the Thompson-McNaughton-Yamada Construction algorithm](https://github.com/hackingoff/scanner-generator/blob/master/lib/scanner_generator/thompson_construction.rb) online.

The algorithm is also addressed in [Aho's Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201100886), though its explanation is sparse on implementation details. You can also learn from [an implementation of the Thompson Construction in C](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/nfa.c.txt) by the excellent Russ Cox, who described it some detail in a popular article about [regular expression matching](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html).

Comment: You're most welcome. If you're in a compilers course and have to build a full-on scanner, run into Context Free Grammars and their first/follow sets, or need to build parsers, http://hackingoff.com  can help with those too.

Answer (score 1):

In the GitHub repository below, you can find a Java implementation of Thompson's construction where first an NFA is being created from the regex and then an input string is being matched against that NFA:

https://github.com/meghdadFar/regex

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/White-White/RegSwift

No more tedious words. Check out this repo, it translates your regular expression to an NFA and visually shows you the state transitions of an NFA.